# Excel - save range of cells in multiple sheets to pdf with no whitespace

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, export

First timer here!  I've got a spreadsheet which uses multiple worksheets, each sheet formatted like this:

```
**Sheet 1**

Name            Assessment Item 1    Assessment Item 2
Student Name    Feedback Item 1      Feedback Item 2
Student Name    Feedback Item 1      Feedback Item 2

**Sheet 2**

Name            Assessment Item 1    Assessment Item 2
Student Name    Feedback Item 1      Feedback Item 2
Student Name    Feedback Item 1      Feedback Item 2
```

I want to be able to export the title row and one student row (across all sheets) per pdf.  It would mean combining the title row and the 8 student rows (one per sheet) into one sheet, and exporting, I'm thinking.

I've been using this code:

```
Sub copyValueTable()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F2").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"C:\First.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F1,A3:F3").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"C:\Second.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

...and it does what I want, but (a) the pdf has one sheet per page, which means a lot of whitespace, (b) it doesn't all fit to one page, so formatting goes awry, and (c) I'd like it to be more automated, if possible, so that I don't have to create an activesheet range for each of my 150 students...

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Watto :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Revised answer following clarifications in comments (further revised for formatting):**

```
Sub copyValueTable()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim heads
    Dim new_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim rownum
    Dim ns_rownum
    Dim filename
    Dim filepath
    Dim rowcnt

    ' add a new workbook for the summary...
    Set new_sheet = Sheets.add
    rownum = 1
    rowcnt = Sheets(2).Range("A1").End(xlDown).row

    ' loop through rows in outer loop
    For rownum = 2 To rowcnt
        Debug.Print "..on student row " & rownum & " in outer loop..."
        ns_rownum = 1 ' initialise for loop through sheets

        ' loops through sheets (except new)...
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> new_sheet.Name Then
                Debug.Print "....on sheet " & ws.Name & " in inner loop..."

                ' copy heads...
                ws.Rows(1).Copy new_sheet.Rows(ns_rownum)
                ns_rownum = ns_rownum + 1

                ' copy data for current record (paste to ns_rownum row to allow for other sheets)
                ws.Rows(rownum).Copy
                new_sheet.Rows(ns_rownum).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

                ' paste column widths to new sheet on first pass through each sheet
                If rownum = 2 Then
                    ws.Columns("A:Z").Copy
                    new_sheet.Columns("A:Z").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
                End If

                ns_rownum = ns_rownum + 2
            End If
        Next

        ' write to pdf
        filename = Sheets(2).Range("A" & rownum).Value
        filepath = Environ("userprofile") & "\" & filename & ".pdf"
        new_sheet.Rows("1:" & ns_rownum).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
         filename:=filepath, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
         IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

        ' delete data in tmp sheet other than heads ready for next loop through sheets
        Sheets(1).Rows("2:" & ns_rownum).Delete

    Next rownum

    ' clean up
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    new_sheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set new_sheet = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

You will need to replace 'Environ("userprofile")' with the path that you want to use for the pdf files, this will pick up the Windows environment variable for the current users default directory.

This revised script above adds a new temp sheet, takes the heads from the 2nd sheet (as the temp will now be the first) then loops through all rows on 2nd sheet (assuming that the other sheets have the same no of rows as there is one row per student on each). Within this there is an inner loop through the sheets to take the row corresponding to the current student and copy this to the tmp sheet. The Tmp sheet is then exported as a PDF and cleared down ready for the next student.

Please note the assumptions above around each student being on the same row on each sheet. If this is not correct then another mechanism would be required to select from the appropriate rows.

I have copied column widths for columns A:Z, you can adjust the column letters to your requirements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks a lot for your answer!  This doesn't seem to be quite doing what I need, but it's close.  I'll try to explain it more clearly: put first row (title) plus second row from each page into a pdf, named after cell A2 (any page but may as well be the first page); then put first row plus third row from each page into a pdf, named after cell A3; then continue that process until through all sheets.  Is this possible?  Thank you :)

Comment: The version you've given me uses the first page title row, and then puts all the second rows underneath, one after the other.  I need it to go first page title, then first page second row, then second page title, then second page second row, etc.  Once it's done that process, repeat for third row, fourth row etc.

Comment: Okay, let me see if I have this right. You want one PDF per student and each student has the same row across all sheets i.e. student 1 is row 2 on each sheet, student 2 is row 3 and so on. Each PDF should be named by the students name. If i've got this right then it shouldn't be difficult to change. I'll have time to amend later this  morning.

Comment: @SimonWatson I have updated the answer in line with your comments. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks so much for your efforts - if I could buy you a beer, I would!  This is working beautifully, with only one problem - the title row is different on each page, so needs to be in between each of the sheet rows.  In other words, title row page 1 -> student row page 1 -> title row page 2 -> student row page 2 -> title row page 3 -> student row page 3 etc.  If you can manage that, I'm forever in your debt!

Comment: no problem, I will amend now. Do you also want a blank line left between each sheet data e.g. sheet1 title, sheet1 row2, blank line, sheet2 title, sheet2 row2, blank line and so on?

Comment: @SimonWatson I have made the change requested, I have added a blank row between each sheets data, if you do not want this then replace 'ns_rownum = ns_rownum + 2' with 'ns_rownum = ns_rownum + 1'.

Comment: You are a genius!  I just discovered one issue I hadn't noticed, which is that the formatting of the cells is different, so the information is being cut off.  Is there some way of forcing it to keep the formatting of the cells?  Thanks yet again :)

Comment: Is it just the column width that's different or things like the font and alignment?

Comment: It seems to keep colours and most formatting, but just not column vertical and horizontal width.  The vertical is crucial, because some of the cells have full paragraphs in them :)

Comment: @SimonWatson okay, I have adjusted to copy the row height and column width as well now. Please could you mark this as the accepted answer if it meets your requirements.